# How to limit distribution of iOS apps on App Store by hardware requirements

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, info-plist, app-distribution

I have an app that's fairly memory intensive and requires about 2GB of RAM, with a high watermark closer to 3GB.  On devices with less than this, it doesn't work, so I want to find a way of limiting the distribution of the App on App Stores to only devices that will run it.

- On the Google Play Store, I can just specify a minimum RAM size, and
  that works perfectly.
- On the Apple App Store, I can't.  So my question is, what can I do
  instead that would have the same effect?

For example, could I limit by hardware type some other way which would mean that (in practice) only devices with 4GB of RAM or more would be able to use it?  If so, how?

NB. Looking on the App Store, I've seen other apps limit by chipset (e.g. only A14 Bionic or better), but it's not clear how to do this, either in AppStoreConnect or Info.plist